# C# List of Different Data Types

Tags: c#, collections

I am writing an application to track tasks, a bit like project planning software. I have an `Entity` base class and 2 classes which inherit from Entity:

1. Task
2. Activity

The `Task` class is rich in the task details, start date, finish date, description etc. The `Activity` class is simply a container for Task or Activity objects, most of its properties are simply aggregates of its children.

I want to be able to create hierarchies of tasks which means that the children of an Activity must be of data type `Task` or `Activity`.

Should I use `List<Entity>` collection for the children of an `Activity` or is there a better approach please?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct approach, that's what polimorhpism is for :) You can also consider having two lists: one of activities and one of tasks, to have better distinction.

Comment: I hadn't thought that each `Activity` could have a `List<Activity>` and a `List<Task>` property, it makes traversing the hierarchy a little more complex but I agree it does keep the lists more focused. Thanks.